# How can I load certificates with unicode CN using CryptoAPI?

Tags: cryptography, cryptoapi, pfx

I am trying to load certificate from the system store. I am using the function `CertFindCertificateInStore` from CryptoAPI:

```
std::string certName;
CERT_RDN_ATTR subjCN;
subjCN.pszObjId = szOID_COMMON_NAME;
subjCN.dwValueType = CERT_RDN_PRINTABLE_STRING;
subjCN.Value.cbData = 2*(certName.size()); 
subjCN.Value.pbData = (BYTE*)certName.c_str();
CERT_RDN rdn;
rdn.cRDNAttr = 1;
rdn.rgRDNAttr = &subjCN;

cert = CertFindCertificateInStore ( certStore,    
                                    X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
                                    CERT_UNICODE_IS_RDN_ATTRS_FLAG ,
                                    CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_ATTR,
                                    &rdn,
                                    NULL);
```

1. Why do I need to set the dwValueType for `CERT_RDN_ATTR` to `CERT_RDN_PRINTABLE_STRING` instead of `CERT_RDN_UNICODE_STRING`? (I am using Unicode.) With `CERT_RDN_UNICODE_STRING` this code doesn't work.
2. Nevertheless, I can't load certificate with a subject CN containing whitespaces and russian symbols. For simple CN names such as "foo", this code works perfect.

What can I do to load Certificates with a unicode name this way?

Answer (score 1):

If you can understand anything from the gibberish that is the MSDN documentation then you are amazing. Perhaps the following gem can be deconstructed for some illumination:

> The CERT_UNICODE_IS_RDN_ATTRS_FLAG dwFindFlags value is used only with
>   the CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_ATTR and CERT_FIND_ISSUER_ATTR values for
>   dwFindType. CERT_UNICODE_IS_RDN_ATTRS_FLAG must be set if the
>   CERT_RDN_ATTR structure pointed to by pvFindPara was initialized with
>   Unicode strings. Before any comparison is made, the string to be
>   matched is converted by using X509_UNICODE_NAME to provide for Unicode
>   comparisons.

I guess the "string to be matched" is in your `subjCN.Value.pbData` field. Have you converted this using `X509_UNICODE_NAME`? This seems to be something you do in the [`CryptEncodeObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378145%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. Going to that page has made my head hurt. Sorry, you'll have to be the one to suffer through the next steps.

Answer (score 1):

I more carefully looked to the documentation. As I understand now,
certificate name blob contains encoded array of rdn attributes
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382005(v=vs.85).aspx
Each rdn attribute has type - such as UTF8, UNICODE, T.61 and etc.

When using CERT_UNICODE_IS_RDN_ATTRS_FLAG for CertFindCertificateInStore, this function converts suppled string
in RDN attribute from Unicode to RDN attribute type and then matches this value with certificates RDN's.

So I decoded my certificate with CryptDecodedObject, looked at RDN Common Name ant it turned out, that type was CERT_RDN_T61_STRING. Then I set subjCN.dwValueType to CERT_RDN_T61_STRING code had worked. For russian symbols I needed CERT_RDN_UNICODE_STRING.
So CertFindCertificateInStore with CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_ATTR or with CERT_FIND_ISSUER_ATTR is not much use to you, if you don't know exact encodyng of this attribute in certificate.